# cudaGetLastError returns "unknown error"

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, cuda

I am new to CUDA C. I am writing a simple array Add and Reduce, when it runs the error check for copying from the device back to the host I get an "unknown error". I am not sure if the error checker is faulty and not returning the correct cudaError but I can't work out what is wrong.......

```
using namespace std;


#include <iostream>

void CudaAddReduce(int *input, int *output, size_t size);

__global__ void Fill(int *fillItem);

__global__ void Add(int *input1, int *result);

__global__ void Reduce(int *intputArray, int *outputArray);



main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
const int N = 100;
int inp[N];
int outp[N];
size_t size = (N * sizeof(int));

CudaAddReduce(inp,outp,size);

cout << outp[N] << endl;

}

void CudaAddReduce(int *input, int *output, size_t size)
{

// allocate buffers to device 

//input
int *d_input;
if (cudaMalloc(&d_input,size) != cudaSuccess){
    cerr << cudaGetErrorString(cudaGetLastError()) << endl;
    cout << "Input allocation to device" << endl;
    exit(1);
}
////////////////////////////
//output
int *d_output;
if (cudaMalloc(&d_output,size) != cudaSuccess){
    cerr << cudaGetErrorString(cudaGetLastError()) <<endl;
    cout << "output allocation to device" << endl;
    exit(1);
}

//////////////////////////////////
//copy buffers to device from host
//////////////////////////////////
//input
if (cudaMemcpy(d_input, input, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice) != cudaSuccess){
    cerr << cudaGetErrorString(cudaGetLastError()) << endl;
    cout << "Input Copy from host to device" << endl;
    exit(1);
}

/////////////////////////////////
//execute device kernals
/////////////////////////////////
int numThreads = 256;
int numBlocks = 1;

//Fill Kernal
Fill<<<numBlocks,numThreads>>>(d_input);



// Add Kernal
Add<<<numBlocks,numThreads>>>(d_input,d_output);


//execute Reduce Kernal
Reduce<<<numBlocks,numThreads>>>(d_output,d_input);

cudaThreadSynchronize();

/////////////////////////////////
//copy result from device to host
/////////////////////////////////
//output 


if  (cudaMemcpy(output,d_output,size,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost)!= cudaSuccess){
    cerr << cudaGetErrorString(cudaGetLastError()) << endl;
    cout << "Output Copy from device to host" << endl;
    exit(1);
}

//clear device buffers
cudaFree(d_input);
cudaFree(d_output);
} 

__global__ void Fill(int *fillItem)
{
int id = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
fillItem[id] = 1;
}
__global__ void Add (int *input1, int* result)
{
int id = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
result[id] = input1[id] + input1[id];
}
__global__ void Reduce(int *inputArray, int *outputArray)
{
extern __shared__ int sdata[];

// each thread loads one element from global to shared mem
unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x;
unsigned int i = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
sdata[tid] = inputArray[i];
__syncthreads();

// do reduction in shared mem
for(unsigned int s=1; s < blockDim.x; s *= 2)
{
    if(tid % (2*s) == 0)
    {
        sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + s];
    }
__syncthreads();
}


// write result for this block to global mem
if(tid == 0) outputArray[blockIdx.x] = sdata[0];
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Where to start... Each kernel contains out of bounds memory operations, the reduce kernel lacks a shared memory size kernel argument, and the `cout` in your `main` contains out of bounds memory access.

Comment: I don't think a question should be down-voted just because the asker wrote bad code. The question is legitimate (and it even attracted a legitimate answer. It might not deserve any up votes, but don't down-vote it.

Comment: I agree with harrism. Though life may be made easier by the error bing renamed to YouveDoneSomethingStupidWithMemoryError, as that's the only time I've seen it!

Comment: I did downvote it and here's why: it isn't because the code is bad, but because (as originally written) the question shows that almost no effort was made at debugging it. There is memory allocation, *three* separate kernel launches, and host-device memory transfers. Something as simple as commenting out sections of the code and running it would have helped isolate where in the code the first problem is occurring. Even if the questioner didn't understand why it was happening it would have greatly improved the question and simplified the code posted to the question

Comment: See [What Stack Overflow is not...](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128548/163653). This question, as written, is incredibly unlikely to be helpful to anyone else. Ever. But it could if the question was something like "Under what circumstances will the runtime API return ´unknown error'?. Here is a little repro case ..... Can someone explain why this code is failing and what the error message means in this context?". That would be a useful question and answer for others.

Comment: Appologies for the poorly writtne code, I am very new to coding and making a lot of mistakes to get results and that maybe the reason why the code looks poorly debugged. Thanks for the comments, I am learning a lot. I'll also take on board talonmies comments about asking questions. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

EDIT: In your kernels, you are trying to access array elements way out of bounds!
Your array size is 100, yet you are using a thread dimension of 256, each of which is trying to write to that! You need to use consistent sizes.

At which point are you getting the error? The two malloc functions look like they should function correctly, and cudaGetErrorString is unlikely to be wrong. My typical experience with unknown error is that you are trying to copy from or to somewhere you shouldn't, or with the wrong size.

Why are you copying an unassigned array into memory? You never filled out the arrays in main.

Also, you do not need to declare the kernal functions with <<<>>>. Those are only needed when you use the function.

Comment: Thanks, solved the problem. Used your recomendations and launched the shared memory kernal with <<<numBlocks, numThreads, SizeOfSharedMemory>>>

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error, and it turned out to be my OS version. There was a mismatch with one of the dependent libraries. Once I upgraded the OS and then reinstalled the drivers, this error went away.

--John